# Uploading File on DigitalOcean Server

Tags: server, hosting, digital-ocean

I have created a SUbdomain in DegitalOcean Server. Now I need to upload a file on my Server and merge this file with a Subdomain. What should I do?
I need every single detail.

Comment: What exactly do you mean: merge a file with a subdomain?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Please structure it in a way to explain exactly what you need doing (in detail) and what you have tried.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to upload files on DigitalOcean Server. I have just created a Subdomain on my Server.
What I want to do is...I have a website template and I want this to appear when I browse my Subdomain URL.